# IntelliJ w/Gradle 1.11 yielding ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when enabling proGuard

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So Im getting this exception in the IntelliJ 13.1.2 event log regulary:

```
0: 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.resolve.AndroidDslContributor.processSetter(AndroidDslContributor.java:216)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.resolve.AndroidDslContributor.process(AndroidDslContributor.java:171)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.resolve.GradleScriptContributor.processDynamicElements(GradleScriptContributor.java:87)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.resolve.NonCodeMembersContributor.runContributors(NonCodeMembersContributor.java:101)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.resolve.ResolveUtil.processNonCodeMembers(ResolveUtil.java:300)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.resolve.ResolveUtil.processScopeNonCodeMethods(ResolveUtil.java:207)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.resolve.ResolveUtil.doProcessDeclarations(ResolveUtil.java:169)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.resolve.ResolveUtil$2.process(ResolveUtil.java:148)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.resolve.ResolveUtil$2.process(ResolveUtil.java:145)
at com.intellij.psi.util.PsiTreeUtil.treeWalkUp(PsiTreeUtil.java:1005)
```

I have the `Android Support` plugin v10.0 and `Gradle v1.11`. Any tips?

**Edit**
I have two `build.gradle  - one in the master project which only contains the following line:

```
// Top-level build file when add configuration options common to all sub projects/modules.re you ca
```

Here is the build file in the subproject:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../yadayada")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "key"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputFile = file("../build/publish/myapp.apk")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile files('libs/pebble.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/spring-appsensor.jar')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
}
```

**edit 2:**
I have found it to trigger each time I click in the edit window of the .gradle file. It only happens with the gradle file with content.

**edit 3:**
The error stops when I remove the line `proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')`  I tried replacing it with the following to options instead, without success. The only option that works as of now is to disable proguard:

- proguardFile ('proguard-rules.txt')
- proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'

The file `proguard-rules.txt` exists in the same folder as the `build.gradle` file. Note that the documentation specifies that when using `getDefaultProguardFile`, [it fetches a specified default file from the SDK](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard)

Comment: It's probably an error in one of your build files. Have you modified them by hand?

Comment: @scott-barta I now added the contents of the two build files to the question. Does this give any clue?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in there. Are there any other symptoms other than seeing that error in the logs?

Comment: I have found it to trigger each time I click in the edit window of the .gradle file. It only happens with the gradle file with content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to IntelliJ 13.1.3 released on May 26th 2014 solved this issue. Android Studio uses the same source so upgrading to the latest version of AS should also fix it for anyone with the same issue there.